# handleClick ''TypeError: undefined has no properties'' can't find what's undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to delete a row in the backend by clicking on the button which sends the _id of the row to be deleted, but I get this error pointing to the line of the button. I can't understand what this 'undefined' refers to, what am I missing?

```
  34 | {
  35 | todos && todos.map((todo) => ([
  36 |   <p key={todo._id} >{todo.content}</p>,
> 37 |   <button key={i++}  id="del"  onClick={() => {this.handleClick(todo._id)}}/>
  38 | ]
  39 | ))
  40 | }
```

My handleClick is as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
const handleClick = (todo_id) => {
  const delTodo = async () => {
    const del = await Axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/todo/' + todo_id)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('deletado!!')
    })
  }
}
}, [])
```

Comment: Functional components do not have `this`. Also `handleClick` should be declared outside the effect hook

Answer (score 0):

use `handleClick` instead of `this.handleClick`.Because functional component not have `this`.  And also declare the function `handleClick` outSide the `useEffect` not necessary to use inside

**updated**

You are declare do many function . just remove `delTodo` function and add async to `handleClick`

```
 const handleClick = async (todo_id) => {
    const del = await Axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/todo/' + todo_id)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('deletado!!')
    })
 }

<button key={i++}  id="del"  onClick={() => {handleClick(todo._id)}}/>
```

Comment: done so, but now nothing happens when I click the button, not even an error.

Comment: have you declare the function outside instead of inside useEffect

Comment: Yes, still nothing, it is like it can't find the handleClick

Comment: Oh really. Can you provide https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-darkness-fie87?file=/src/TodoList.js

Answer (score 0):

Functional components dont use `this` (arrow functions also have issues with that word too, keep it in mind). Just dont use `this`.